# How to pass cmdopts in pytest to a class?

Tags: python, command-line, automation, pytest

I have the following code in my conftest.py

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
parser.addoption(
    "--env", action="store", default="Alpha", help="my option: type1 or type2"
)

@pytest.fixture
def env(request):
    return request.config.getoption("--env")
```

In my test class, I want to use these options passed: 
My test class contains,

```
class TestClass(): 
    def xyz(env):
         <SomeCodeHere>
```

The cmdopts are picked up when I run the functions using pytest -q  (Without adding the functions inside a class) but when they are inside the class, none of the cmdopts are getting picked up.

Note when I try to print out my env: I get an instance like : src.com.abc.efg.hij.FileName.TestClass instance at 0xblablabla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I did not use the self variable in my method in def(env), so env was being taken up as an equivalent of the self variable.